# Compute the expected value of the surplus water.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Water flows in and out of a dam such that the daily inflow is uniform on
>   $[0, 2]$ (liters) and the daily outflow is uniform on $[0, 1]$,
>   independently of the inflow. Each day the surplus water (if there is
>   any) is collected for an irrigation project. Compute the expected
>   amount of surplus water in a given day.

Let $X=$ inflow and $Y=$outflow. Then $X\sim \text{unif}[0,2]$ and $Y\sim \text{unif}[0,1]$ and we denote the surplus as $g(X,Y)=Z=X-Y.$

By independence, it follows that $f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)=1\cdot1/2=1/2.$ The range of $Z$ is $[0,2]$, since on a given day one can have zero outflow and 2 inflow or zero inflow and zero outflow. The formula for the expected value of $g(X,Y)$ is

$$E(g(X,Y))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y)f(x,y) \ dxdy \tag{1}$$

But how do I determine the bounds for this doubleintegral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should have $g(X,Y)=Z=\max(0,X-Y).$

Note that $0 \le x \le 2$ and $0 \le y \le 1$.

\begin{align}E(g(X,Y))&= \int_0^1\int_0^2 g(x,y) f(x,y) \,\, dxdy \\
&=\int_0^1\int_y^2 (x-y) f(x,y)\,\, dxdy\end{align}

Comment: So, how would one compute $max(0,X-Y)$? And why do we need that max there? Also, why didin't it work with the linearity method?

Comment: that has to do with the definition of surplus, since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it is possible for $X-Y$ to be negative right?

Comment: Ahh... I understand why we need to use the maxfunction. But how can I compute that by hand? How is it done? By the way it gives me $7/12$ in  Maple so it's correct.

Comment: I have simplied the integral a little bit, can you complete it?

Comment: Yes, it's easy to complete it, but I don't understnad how you got from the first line to the second. Why did you replace 0 by $y$?

Comment: I consider the question when does $x-y \ge 0$, because otherwise, it evaluates to $0$. $x-y \ge 0$ is equivalent to $x \ge y$, hence the lower limit of $y$.

Comment: Thanks. One last question. Why didn't the linearity method work and, are there other easier methods?

Comment: we do not have $E(\max(X,Y))=\max(E(X), E(Y))$ in general. perhaps there is an easier method, I do not know.